# Django PDF media files are not displayed on my web page

Tags: django, django-templates

I have been looking on the internet all over the place for this
and it seems that everything is in check, also media images are very well displayed

so I have a django web app that has a FileField where you can upload pdfs and now I am trying to display thouse pdfs but they get displayed with the error as the image below shows.

**settings.py**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

**show_pdf.html**

```
<iframe
        src="{{pdf.url}}"
    frameBorder="0"
    scrolling="auto"
    height="1200px"
    width="1200px"
></iframe>
```

**models.py**

```
class File_pdf(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='portfolio/pdfs')
    main_resume = models.BooleanField(default=False,help_text="set only one pdf as the main pdf for the main page")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('',include('portfolio.urls')),
        path('blog/',include('blog.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
def pdf_view(request,pdf_id,resume):
    dic = {}
    if resume == "yes":
        pdf_files = File_pdf.objects.filter(main_resume=True)
        pdf_file = pdf_files[0]
        dic['pdf'] = pdf_file.pdf
        dic['title'] = pdf_file.title
    else:
        pdf_files = get_object_or_404(File_pdf,pk=pdf_id)
        pdf_file = pdf_files[0]
        dic['pdf'] = pdf_file.pdf
        dic['title'] = pdf_file.title
```

The error looks like this:

[image]

this is actually the correct link

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload the currently open page and override the locally cached version by **ctrl+shift+r**. This should help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your **settings.py** add the following code:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM <your localhost URL>'
```

for example

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
```

Comment: This is actually usefull to know, thanks for replying. but it turns out that everything was correct but the brave cache somehow was in conflict with the X_FRAME_OPTIONS updating itself. so after deleting braves cache it was enough

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that everything was correct but the brave cache somehow was in conflict with the X_FRAME_OPTIONS updating itself. so after deleting brave's cache it was enough :)